# triple error when trying to execute SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the code I am trying to execute.

```
SELECT * Catagory
FROM Catagory
LEFT JOIN products.Price
ON Catagory.Category=products.Price
WHERE ((Catagory.Category='Ring' OR Catagory.Category='Earings') AND(products.Price<=30))
ORDER BY products.Price
```

I'm not sure if it's the fact that I'm trying to do a join or maybe the permissions need to be reset or something.

The code seems to work when using other tables in the database and I'm pretty sure that this one has all the same settings.

```
SELECT * Catagory
FROM Catagory
LEFT JOIN products.Price
ON Catagory.Category=products.Price
WHERE ((Catagory.Category='Ring' OR Catagory.Category='Earings') AND(products.Price<=30))
ORDER BY products.Price LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Catagory
FROM Catagory
LEFT JOIN products.Price
ON Catagory.Category=products' at line 1

Warning in ./libraries/DbQbe.php#1669
array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Util' not found

Backtrace

./libraries/DbQbe.php#1669: array_map(
string 'Util::backquote',
array,
)
./libraries/DbQbe.php#1556: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->_getJoinForFromClause( array,
array,
)
./libraries/DbQbe.php#1789: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->_getFromClause(array)
./libraries/DbQbe.php#1857: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->_getSQLQuery(array)
./db_qbe.php#153: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->getSelectionForm()


Warning in ./libraries/DbQbe.php#1670
implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Backtrace

./libraries/DbQbe.php#1670: implode(
string ', ',
NULL,
)
./libraries/DbQbe.php#1556: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->_getJoinForFromClause(
array,
array,
)
./libraries/DbQbe.php#1789: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->_getFromClause(array)
./libraries/DbQbe.php#1857: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->_getSQLQuery(array)
./db_qbe.php#153: PMA\libraries\DbQbe->getSelectionForm()
```

Comment: `SELECT * Catagory FROM Catagory` should that be `SELECT * FROM Category`?

Comment: Are both your tables in the same database?

Comment: And... are you sure you want to equi-join two tables on  'Category' (a string) being equal to  'Price' (a number)?

Comment: @JanR Tried    SELECT * FROM category and got the following error.  #1146 - Table '2450097_onlinestore.catagory' doesn't exist

Comment: #1146 - Table '2450097_onlinestore.catagory' doesn't exist  is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong it should be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Catagory c
LEFT JOIN products p
ON c.Category=p.Price
WHERE ((c.Category='Ring' OR c.Category='Earings') AND(p.Price<=30))
ORDER BY p.Price;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple wrong in the statement

1)

```
SELECT * Catagory FROM Catagory
```

Shloud be

```
SELECT * FROM Catagory
```

or

```
SELECT Catagory FROM Catagory
```

2)

```
LEFT JOIN products.Price ON Catagory.Category=products.Price
```

You can not use this as the data in those links are not the same.
For ex. you can link two columns that have numbers or two columns that have names but you can not link a number to a name.

The second one is not an error it is more like a wrong doing